# Date format issue causing in websphere

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jboss, websphere

I need a help. Below are the 2 same select queries running Jboss and websphere which in installed in linux box. In Jboss query works fine, but fails in websphere. Codebase for both are same.
**Jboss**

```
SELECT MODIFIED_DATE FROM /*Query Builder Clause*/ ACA_RULE WHERE  ACA_RULE_CID = '1455' AND NVL(to_date('**12/14/2015 8:48:41**', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), SYSDATE)=decode(MODIFIED_DATE,null,SYSDATE,MODIFIED_DATE)
```

**Websphere**

```
SELECT MODIFIED_DATE FROM /*Query Builder Clause*/ ACA_RULE WHERE  ACA_RULE_CID = '1189' AND NVL(to_date(**'2010-3-17 11.30.10.0'**, 'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), SYSDATE)=decode(MODIFIED_DATE,null,SYSDATE,MODIFIED_DATE)
```

Hence throws

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: '2010-3-17 11.30.10.0 ==> 2010 is not a valid month. Change your date pattern.

Comment: You use the same datetime format `'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'` in both queries but your source data formats are  different  `'12/14/2015 8:48:41'`  and   `'2010-3-17 11.30.10.0'`

Comment: yes i use the same data format and same code .. only server is different. In jboss : 12/14/2015 8:48:41 But websphere it get converted to '2010-3-17 11.30.10.0' and throw oracle exception

Comment: Are `to_date('**12/14/2015 8:48:41**', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` and  `to_date(**'2010-3-17 11.30.10.0'**, 'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` the same?

Comment: Is your question organized incorrectly? I think the other comments are pointing out that you show two different queries under the headings "Jboss" and "Webshere". Are you saying that both of those queries actually both work on Jboss and both give the error on WebSphere? If  so, you should reword the question.

Comment: Try to set different locale via JVM generic args in WAS (-Duser.language=XX -Duser.country=XX). Looks like you are running on different server, with different default locale set.

Comment: I did try to set different locale and time zone as well. Also upraded ojdbc to Higher version

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this;

**Websphere**

```
SELECT MODIFIED_DATE FROM /*Query Builder Clause*/ ACA_RULE WHERE  ACA_RULE_CID = '1189' AND NVL(to_date(**'2010-3-17 11.30.10'**, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss'), SYSDATE)=decode(MODIFIED_DATE,null,SYSDATE,MODIFIED_DATE)
```

Comment: i should not modify the date format.Query should be be working same as how it is working in Jboss. Date format should be MM-DD-YYYY. I tried to upgrade to higher version ojdbc6.jar in websphere still did not worked for me. Also I tried to set NLS_DATE format in wepsphere setting.